# FindMinimum is running too slow

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

For defined a function `h[x_?NumericQ]`, I can get a plot of the function from `Plot` function in about seven seconds. But when I try to evaluate

`FindMinimum[h[x], {x, 3000}]`

it starts to evaluate. but I cannot see the result for a long time. How can the function `FindMinimum` (with some parameters) be optimized to get a faster computation?

Comment: Your `h[x]`seems to be numeric, try `NMinimize` as numeric minimizer

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What is the biggest difference between the `NMinimize` and `FindMinimum`? What options use with `NMinimize'?

Comment: @ avan1235 : `NMinimize` tries to find a global minimum. Usually you don't need to give a starting value. Why didn't you provide the code of `h[]`?

Comment: Could you use `StepMonitor` to see how the search is progressing?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I can but it is a little complicated fuction fuild of anouther functions functions

Comment: @ChrisK I have just edited `h[x]` to be fully numeric  function and then tried `FindMinimum[h[x], {x, 3000.,3000.,5000.},StepMonitor:>Print["Step to x=", x]]` and got
'Step to x = 4500.
Step to x = 4040.05
Step to x = 3931.21
Step to x = 3941.92
Step to x = 3941.73
Step to x = 3941.73' with the error in the end "The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances." What can I do?

Comment: Is that close to the minimum you see using `Plot`?

Comment: @ChrisK Yes, it is

Comment: Maybe that's close enough?